# Displaying an array element in view of angular vs angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

In AngularJS, when I wanted to display an specific element from an array, within my view, I would simply reference it like this:

```
<span>{{contact.emails[0].email_address}}</span>
```

But for some reason, with the same setup in Angular, I get the error:

```
Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'email_address' of undefined
```

So if I return an object of contact that contains an emails array, how do I reference the first item on the array?

Comment: try it with the `?` operator, may be for the first time the template is rendered, the array is still `undefined`. Like, `{{ contact?.emails[0]?.email_address }}`

Comment: DV for lack of research, there are at least 3 dups of this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span>{{contact.emails[0]?.email_address}}</span>
```

This is most likely because your emails array is being async loaded, so it is null till your service returns. Using ? makes so it won't try to access the 'email_address' property till its defined, thus not throwing an error at load.

Comment: wdanda, that worked! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to do a

```
console.log(contact.emails[0])
```

Because this error means the first item of your array doesn't exist.

Otherwise, if it existed, it would work like that !

```
<span>{{contact.emails[0].email_address}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Try this:
```

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]='contact.emails && contact.emails.length > 0'>
  <span>{{contact.emails[0].email_address}}</span>
</ng-template>
```